# Xcode Beta 6.3 magically delegates tasks to other threads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, storyboard

We've came onto this **strange** bug in our project (I hope it's a bug not just our fault). Let's jump straight into the problem.

Our application is *Storyboard* based, of course it connects to the external API etc. But we've faced this strange thing that regular implementation of `prepareForSegue:` and things related to **segues** automagically delegates things to other threads. Just a small example - when I do `NSLog(@"Sample log")` in `viewDidLoad` it doesn't get fired when it should but it gets called in the random time that's why I guessed that something might get delegated to the other-than-main thread. Firstly I thought that the networking layer may cause this because of blocks and so but even when I put direc logs into the application they get called in a random time! We've tried to check the thread in debugger and it shows us thet everything happens in the main thread. **Strange, right?**

Anyway, my colleagues check this against the different versions of Xcode because on my machine there are bothe 6.2 and 6.3 Beta. When we compile this on a computer with only 6.3 installed everything works properly! Is it possible that 6.3 Beta introduces some changes which handles segues differently than previous versions? Or maybe we should start seeking for the troubles some oher place?